# Shopware 6: how to prove if product has variants

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

If I call a product, I will check if **the product has variants**.

Currently, I make it with an additional request using `product.id`

```js
const criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setLimit(1);
criteria.addFilter(
    Criteria.equals('product.parentId', this.product.id)
);
this.productRepository
    .search(criteria)
    .then((result) => {
        ...
    });
```

I can't find a suitable attribute (field) like e.g. `product.hasVariant`.

I think this is a simple parent:child relationship. I'm wondering if the only way to achieve this goal is in its children (which have the `product.parentId` field).

Question:
— Is there an attribute, which define, if product has variants?
— … or **how to define, if a product has variants**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a field called `childCount`.

JS:

```js
criteria.addFilter(Criteria.range('childCount', { gt: 0 }));
```

API:

```json
{
    "filter": [
        {
            "type": "range",
            "field": "childCount",
            "parameters": {
                "gt": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```